# How to generate an NSURLRequest to download a file from a WebDAV server like MobileME

Tags: iphone

Should I mention 
`[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"]` ? 
and what should I enter in the 
`[request setHTTPBody: ?]` ? 
OR should I just leave it empty?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in case any body would like to know , my assumptions work fine.
just have to set the `[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];` and then making a NSURLConnection with such request Downloads the specified content at that URL.